# What is the best pratice to get a file attribute(such as read only), and security attribute(such as read deny write deny)?

Tags: c++, windows, security, file-attributes

I am programming in C++ MFC, windows.

What is the best practice to get a file attribute(such as read only), and security attribute(such as read deny write deny) in windows XP, Vista, and Win7?

and What is the best practice to modify a file attribuute and security attribute?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check [C++ - How to set file permissions (cross platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592448/c-how-to-set-file-permissions-cross-platform) ?

Also, take a look here [Windows Access Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374860(VS.85.aspx))