# Why i can't copy a font file to c:\Windows\Fonts thought CopyFile

Tags: c++

i want to install a new font in my system,but something wrong in my code,i can't find out what mistake i had make.After i call CopyFile,the file didn't exists in C:\Windows\Fonts.Can you give me some suggestion?Thank you.
Here is my code:

```
`//the source file
string sSourceDir = "F:\\my_job\\font\\";
//the file name
string sFontFileName = "jdqw.TTF";
string sFontName = "jdqw";
TCHAR sWinDir[MAX_PATH];

GetWindowsDirectory(sWinDir, MAX_PATH);

string sFontDir(sWinDir);
//make the path like C:\\Windows\\Fonts
sFontDir += "\\Fonts\\";
string sFOTFile = sFontDir;
sFOTFile += sFontFileName.substr(0, sFontFileName.length() - 4);
sFOTFile += ".FOT";
string source = sSourceDir;
string dest = sFontDir;
source += sFontFileName;
dest += sFontFileName;

//copy file
cout << source.c_str() << "   " << dest.c_str() << endl;
cout << CopyFile(source.c_str(), dest.c_str(), FALSE) << endl;
cout << GetLastError() << endl;`
```

Comment: What do `CopyFile` (and `GetLastError`) return? (Also, I"m guessing it's a lack of permissions)

Comment: the CopyFile return 1,and GetLaseError value is 0,my permissions is manager.the file exists in C:\Windows\Fonts,but it's unused.no name,no attribute,once flash,it gone

Comment: I dont think its possible to copy a font to fonts folder without installing a font first. `CreateScalableFontResource` and `AddFontResource` APIs are required

Comment: i read an article that said two step to install a new font.First,copy a font to fonts folder,next call AddFontResourcel and register in regedit...its that right?

Comment: Yeah you are right try the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149407/set-folder-permission-using-plain-c-or-java

Comment: This is how Microsoft guide you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144833.aspx

Comment: the problem is still exists...what confuse me is that after call CopyFile, a file which i can't read and write exists,and flash the folder,it's gone.And i try to copy and paste the font into this folder,system install it and then the font can use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [pretty good description by Michael Kaplan](http://www.siao2.com/2006/06/25/646701.aspx). In short, you can't and shouldn't copy files there because it is a virtual view. Instead, use the appropriate method: Call `AddFontResourceEx`, pass the appropriate flags. If the font is system-wide available,  broadcast `WM_FONTCHANGE`. To install the font permanently, you require admin rights (ie. UAC elevation), because you need to list the font filename under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.

You might want to consider doing these steps from your installer instead, since that usually runs with the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks all.I have solved this problem.It seem that copy a file to a virtual view like C:\Windows\Fonts is not allowed.So I don't copy it,I use the absolute path of the font file in the function(AddFontResource),it is a little bad that after thd machine reboot,the font have to install once againt.