# How do I use chmod with Node.js

Tags: node.js, chmod, fs

How do I use chmod with Node.js?

There is a method in the package `fs`, which should do this, but I don't know what it takes as the second argument.

> **fs.chmod(path, mode, [callback])**
>
> Asynchronous chmod(2). No arguments other than a possible exception are given to the completion callback.
>
> **fs.chmodSync(path, mode)**
>
> Synchronous chmod(2).

(from the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmod_path_mode_callback))

If I do something like

```
fs.chmodSync('test', 0755);
```

nothing happens (the file isn't changed to that mode).

```
fs.chmodSync('test', '+x');
```

doesn't work either.

I'm working on a Windows machine btw.

Comment: I think windows permissions are more complicated... you might want to open an issue on github if you can't solve it.

Comment: Have to agree with @thejh on this one... Windows file permissions are much more complicated.  You may need to execute commands to cmd.exe or similar.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

According to its sourcecode [`/lib/fs.js`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js) on line 508:

```
fs.chmodSync = function(path, mode) {
  return binding.chmod(pathModule._makeLong(path), modeNum(mode));
};
```

and line 203:

```
function modeNum(m, def) {
  switch (typeof m) {
    case 'number': return m;
    case 'string': return parseInt(m, 8);
    default:
      if (def) {
        return modeNum(def);
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
  }
}
```

it takes either an octal number or a string.

e.g.

```
fs.chmodSync('test', 0755);
fs.chmodSync('test', '755');
```

It doesn't work in your case because the file modes only exist on *nix machines.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't played with MSYS, and simply don't know how it works. Maybe it's just a kind of simulation(forgive me if I'm wrong). This post may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682672/how-does-chmod-work-for-windows

Comment: MSYS seems to ignore file modes.

Answer (score 24):

The correct way to specify Octal is as follows:

```
fs.chmodSync('test', 0o755);
```

Refer to the file modes [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmod_path_mode_callback).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, instead of on Octal number or string, you need to use `fs.constants` or `fsPromises.constants`. For example, to change a file to open for read only access you would use:

```js
fs.chmodSync(filePath, fs.constants.O_RDONLY)
```

You can find the values for `fs.constants` here: [Node File System Constants](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs-constants)