# Node.js copy UNIX executable file (Mac OS X)

Tags: node.js

So I have an executable UNIX file (which I extracted from a Mac App), and tried to duplicate it. The code is:

```
var dat = fs.readFileSync("~/FileZilla.app/Contents/MacOS/filezilla",{ flags:'r', encoding:"binary"});
fs.writeFileSync("~/filezilla_copy", dat,{ flags: 'w',  encoding: "binary",});
```

But what I end up getting is an un-readable document file and not a UNIX EXE file. I can't even run it through terminal, although supposedly I created an exact duplicate of the original file. How do I get this file to be recognized as a UNIX file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the mode of the file to set the execute bit, use `fs.chmodSync()`. See here for details: [How do I use chmod with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756639/how-do-i-use-chmod-with-node-js)