# Block read/write/delete file in Ubuntu and Windows with Node.js

Tags: node.js, chmod, file-access

I'm trying to block the access to read, write and delete a file for all users in both Ubuntu and Windows with Node.js. In Ubuntu, I can do it with `fs.chmodSync(file, 0000)`, but it doesn't work on Windows. Could someone recommend me a easy way to achieve it in both platforms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756639/how-do-i-use-chmod-with-node-js? You cannot use chmod on Windows.

Comment: You can but with limited option: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/LQniG9_Q6go