# Write an executable .sh file via fs.writeFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, chmod

Is there a way to write an executable shell script file using fs.writeFileSync

Fundamentally i'm trying to output a .sh file via a CLI and i want that .sh file to be executable so i do not need to manually run a chmod +x "filename" once the file gets outputted from CLI.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmodsync_path_mode & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756639/how-do-i-use-chmod-with-node-js

Comment: the nodeJS filesystem module is your way to go

Comment: you can even create shell scripts that will get interpreted by node instead of bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the script file and set the permissions within Node using the filesystem (`fs`) module.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var script_name = "myscript.sh";
var script_content = "echo Hello world!";

fs.writeFileSync(script_name, script_content);
fs.chmodSync(script_name, "755");
```

Consider looking [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-their-attributes) for more information on understanding rights