# Fixing file permissions after modifying in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, executable, file-permissions, self-modifying

I'm saving my data in the executable file of the program. I copy it to a temporary file, overwrite a part starting at a *'magic string'* and rename it to the original. I know this is a bad idea, but I'm doing it just for experimenting.

I got everything to work so far, except for that I have to re-enable "Allow running as an executable" each time the file is replaced. What ways are there to solve this?

Additional information: I use linux.

Comment: you can add it to the make file or a script depending on what kind of scripting you know , to chmod it how you see fit when needed

Comment: Just so I get this straight: you're copying an executable image elsewhere, looking for a certain pattern, modifying the binary image in place, and then plan on executing it again? This can ONLY end in tears.

Comment: @Chris I know; it's much better to just store the data somewhere else. Imagine what would happen if the PC crashed while modifying the file.

Comment: do you want to run "chmod +x <filename>" from inside your C++ program ?

Comment: Or worse, imagine what might happen if it didn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - How to set file permissions (cross platform)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592448/c-how-to-set-file-permissions-cross-platform)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to avoid using system(), you can use

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

It is documented in http://linux.die.net/man/3/chmod.

See also: [C++ - How to set file permissions (cross platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592448/c-how-to-set-file-permissions-cross-platform).

Answer (score 7):

If you include `stdlib.h`, you can use `system("command")`.

Try it:

```
system("chmod 755 yourExeFile")
```

Comment: Use 755 if you prefer not getting hacked.

Comment: That did the job! Very simple too.

Comment: maybe add the semicolon in above? :)