# Setting permissions to a directory using C++

Tags: c++, linux

I try to create new directory and set its permissions (using at most c++11 and without boost) so user, group and others can list files inside read them and write new files (**linux** environment).

```cpp
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void) {
  const char* path = "/tmp/newDir";
  mode_t process_mask = umask(0);
  int syscall_status = mkdir(path, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
  umask(process_mask);
  return syscall_status;
}
```

This code is based on the man (2) page of mkdir (and umask). 
However the created directory has `rwxr-xr-x` permissions (no write for group and others). 
I also tried using chmod syscall on the directory but it didn't solve the problem. Other sources in stackoverflow treated files (rather than folders), and trying to apply the file-methods on my directory didn't work as well.

Also, I want to avoid calling system() from stdlib, this is the last option I'll use if I don't find a solution (security considerations).

Comment: I strongly recommend Boost.Filesystem. Or, if you have C++17, `<filesystem>`

Comment: At what privilege level are you running the program?

Comment: @AndyG I can't use boost and compile with c++11 (can't newer).

Comment: @ryyker user level, and I have rwx permissions for the parent dir /tmp/

Comment: @RonU: My sympathies about your C++ version :-). The inability to use Boost isn't the worst thing overall; it tends to creep into your codebase and bloat your headers anyway.

Comment: @RonU Have you verified the mkdir call is succeeding? You could be unknowingly letting an EEXIST slide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing file permissions after modifying in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9287048/608639), [How to set file permissions (cross platform) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592448/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww I updated the question to explain how it is different

Comment: It looks like you have ACL applied. Which is not strange as you do that on /tmp folder which shared by all users. umask alone can't breach that

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char* path = "/tmp/newDir";
> ```

Besides the syntax error, this is ill-formed since C++11. Prior to that, this would be using a deprecated conversion. String literals are const in C++ -> Use pointer to const.

Other than that, the program is correct assuming a POSIX system. If it fails, then you can check `errno` to see why. If you don't get all permissions: Check if the parent directory has a default ACL; that would override umask.

A portable way of creating a directory in C++ is `std::filesystem::create_directory` and a way of setting permissions is `std::filesystem::permissions`.

Comment: the path variable is just something I wrote to focus the question, in the actual code it is a const string from somewhere else and there are no typos ofcourse :) .   The std::filesystem won't help me because I'm using c++11 (i wrote that in the comments but I'll edit the question for further clarity)

Comment: @RonU you should look at ACL, that's the most important part of this. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie when I run 'chmod 777 /tmp/newDir' through the terminal (with the same user that runs the program) it grants the required permissions to the dir , so does it make sense that the ACL is blocking me?

Comment: @RonU https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328806/acl-named-group-permissions-not-overriding-file-permissions-why