# Is there a platform-indepenent way of setting file permissions with gradle?

Tags: java, linux, windows, gradle, file-permissions

I am developing my program on redhat 6 and I set my permissions in Gradle with

```
commandLine 'chmod', '-R', '775', '<myFolder>'
```

This is great but it will not work on Windows. Does Gradle have a platform-independent way of setting program permissions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592448/c-how-to-set-file-permissions-cross-platform?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way gradle is implemented you should be able to write your own tasks (or plugins if needed). And Java should have a way to set file permissions platform-independent.

You can even use dependencies for your gradle plugin via buildscript {}.

Maybe you need a seperate plugin for that, more information on http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html