# How to set file permission on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, permissions, runtime

I need to figure out how to write functions to control access to resources on Windows 8.1. On Windows 7 and earlier versions, it seems I can use Access Control List related functions provided in Win32 API to write things like that,

[C++ - How to set file permissions (cross platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592448/c-how-to-set-file-permissions-cross-platform)

but wonder how to do the same thing on the latest Windows 8.1, since Win32 is replaced by WinRT.

I'm considering using C++, but any suggestion to accomplish this task is welcomed.

Comment: Win32 still exists on Windows 8.1. I doubt WinRT even has file permissions since everything is locked down by default.

Comment: So you mean Win32 applications/codes written and tested on Windows 7 can work on Windows 8 (fairly perfectly or so)? Sorry, I don't have a Windows 8.1 device right now to test my codes which I'm currently writing on Windows 7.

Comment: Other than WindowsRT (e.g. on a tablet), which supports Store apps only, yes.